# Google APIs to use?

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic2, google-translate

i am currently working on a project which will use the device's camera function to take a photo of a ingredient list and then it will display text in the image.I have used google cloud vision API to display the text.However i want to be able to highlight the text that was displayed on the image itself.Something like the google translate application where the user takes a picture and the screen display a box to let the user to draw out which of the words they wanted to translate.May i know which API do i need to use in order to create this function?

As requested: This is what i had done so far, this is to display the text in images to a console.log()

```
    takePicture() {
    Camera.getPicture({

      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,

      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 1000
    }).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      //this.detectText(imageData);
      this.getVision(imageData);
      //console.log(imageData);

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }



    getVision(base64image: string) {
    this.testService.getVisionLabels(base64image)
      .subscribe((sub) => {

        this.labels = sub.responses[0].textAnnotations;

        this.getText();


      });
  }

getText() {

this.labels.forEach((label) => { 
  let translation = {search: label.description, result: ''};
  //console.log(label.description);
  console.log(label.description);
});
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have tried?

Comment: I'm not sure. I added a bunch of tags to your question that are relevant. Maybe someone else, with more experience in hybrid mobile apps will come along and help. If you have something besides a TypeScript type error, add the JavaScript tag to your question as well.

Comment: Hi there, the code i have shared above is working fine however my supervisor wants me to do something like google translate(image translation,which takes a picture and highlights the text on the picture itself).Which i have no clue about which API should i use.

Comment: added the google translate tag, sorry IDK